# How to make a responsive navigation bar with menu icon

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive navigation bar with responsive style, if the size of screen is smaller than 750px then in the navigation bar will appear the menu icon in the middle and when hovering it will display the options in the list, below is my code, and possibly i have overlapped css styling.

```css
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a2d4c3;
  margin: 3px 50px 3px 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hidden:hover a {
  background-color: #dab756;
  display: block;
}

.hidden:hover ul a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden li ul {
  display: none;
}

.hidden li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

.hidden ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.hidden .hidden:hover li a {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .hidden ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }

  .hidden li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div class="topnav">
        <ul class="hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I think that this snippet is the same as you want...

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  header {
    background: #181818;
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .inner {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 120px;
    color: #eee;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  nav > ul {
    float: left;
  }
  nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 70px;
  }
  nav > ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  nav ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  nav > ul > li > a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
  }
  nav a {
    color: white;
  }
  nav > ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
  }
  nav > ul li ul li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  [type="checkbox"],
  label {
    display: none;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    nav ul {
      display: none;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      background: #222;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    label:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 5px;
      background: #777;
      margin: 7px 5px;
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px #777, 0px 20px 0px #777
    }
    [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
      display: block;
      z-index: 9999;
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      left: 20px;
    }
    nav a {
      color: #777;
    }
    nav ul li {
      display: block;
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      background: #222;
      text-indent: 20px;
    }
    nav > ul > li {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    nav > ul li ul li {
      display: block;
      float: none;
    }
    nav > ul li ul {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      float: none;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 26px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="inner">
        <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="nav" /><label for="nav"></label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Not exactly the result that i am looking for, but anyway thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Can you move the icon in the middle, and make it just by hover not click  to display the options of menu?

Comment: I just got success to move icon in middle...check the snippet now I am trying to give it hover effect. @SachiTakamori

Comment: :D Thanks mate, almost there :D

Comment: @SachiTakamori if width becomes below 768px than it converts into tablet mode and in tablet mode, you can not give hover effect because there you can touch only...so we cant give hover effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188019/discussion-between-sachi-takamori-and-mk-patel).

Answer (score 1):

you need to change classes of your nav with javascript depending on conditions something like given below and then style this changed classes accordingly.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
           x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
   </script>
```

[or refere this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)

Comment: I am required to use only Html and CSS

Comment: In theory it should not be difficult, but i am not familiar with css yet.

Comment: ok. It is very easy to do with bootstrap but you wont to use it, it's ok no problem I will try my best to solve your problem